# Where can I find timezone settings in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, architecture, continuous-integration, devops

I tried to find it in configuration management of Jenkins it's not there.

I want to share screenshot of time zone settings of Jenkins 
where I would get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202070/how-to-change-the-time-zone-in-jenkins) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the time zone in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202070/how-to-change-the-time-zone-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure the Timezone in Jenkins Configuration Management. If you need to set the timezone for Jenkins, you can specify it in the start command:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

> java -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/Los_Angeles

This will set your Jenkins timezone to specified region.

If you need current time in different timezones to be displayed with builds, you can use this chrome plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jenkins-timezone-localize/pljmfmaidfeachglaofbhffflhbooggg

But it currently supports only three timezones.