# What can cause difference in timestamps between console view and blueocean view?

Tags: jenkins, timestamp, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I've notice that there are different timestamps for same job in console and blueocean view.

Timestamps in Console Output show correct time for my timezone. In blueocean view timestamps are shifted by two hours. That could indicate that blueocean use different timezone. Did someone encounter same issue and know if there is a way to fix that?

It is declarative pipeline and timestamps have been added with:

```
options {
    timestamps()
}
```

Jenkins 2.164.2
blueocean 1.14.0
timestamper 1.9

Comment: What timezone you are in? I would guess that one of the view uses UTC and the other uses something like the one from where it is run on.

Comment: The difference between UTC and GMT+1 are 2 hours: http://www.timebie.com/timezone/universalberlin.php so the views are just using different timezones.

Comment: W. Europe Standard Time (GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna. It do seems that Console Output reflects timezone in which job has been run (in this case UTC+2) and timezone in Blue Ocean is fixed on UTC+0.

Comment: So the question is if it is possible to make Blue Ocean to use correct timezone for Jenkins location?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202070/how-to-change-the-time-zone-in-jenkins

Comment: Solutions provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202070/how-to-change-the-time-zone-in-jenkins allow to change timezone which is displayed in SystemInfo under org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone. This change will be reflected in Console Output (as long as it doesn't use browser timezone) and Build History window but it will not affect Blue Ocean view in which UTC+0 is still in use.

Comment: I am facing same issue, (timezone gap in console vs BO), is there any update? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug and it doesn't look like it is going to get fixed anytime soon.

See: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52938

Comment: The issue you are referring to is about timestamps not appearing at all. Timestamps show up in my blueocean pipeline, but just like OP, with timezone z (utc).

Comment: This is still almost certainly a Jenkins/blue ocean/ timestamper bug or unimplemented feature.  Too bad this can't be configured to use something other than UTC.  Here is another link to an open Jenkins issue https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44195